# How load data in datagrid in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

In WinForms i do this:

```
var fromtable = from a in Table1 select a;
DataGridView.DataSource = fromtable;
```

And i see data. How make same in wpf application?

If i do like this:

```
Museum_TrueEntities me = new Museum_TrueEntities();
 var test = from a in me.Authors select a;
 dataGrid1.ItemsSource = test;
```

In result DataGrid is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont forget to set AutogenerateColumns=true in your datagrid.

if you create the columns by your self post some xaml and set the correct binding.

Answer (score 2):

For Datatable we do

```
mydatagrid.ItemSource = mydatatable.DefaultView
```